# In MVVM, I have some DataTable as data source. Should I add new model to centralized them?

Tags: c#, mvvm

VM can be responsible for logic and UI data, and can combine multiple model.

Since these data are existing types, do I just need to put them in the ViewModel as properties?

Or need to create a model class to put them?

And where should I put the logical processing results of these data? VM Or M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you convert models to view models and back again. Its not very common to include your models in your viewmodels... Yeah this seems like code duplication (and it is) however it [separates your concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and makes sure you aren't mixing business logic and UI concerns and your data-layer (or vice versa).

On saying that MVVM is just a pattern and not a religion, you need to do what seems most logical and maintainable for you

Comment: I am applying MVVM to my developed program (for learning purposes). 
So before I completely understand and use it flexibly, I choose to use the most religions way at first. And... So, where should I put them?